# Implementing Jquery Auto Suggest Dev Bridge

Tags: jquery, autosuggest

I try to implement this auto suggest from http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

My PHP code is not working but lookup function is only showing up results.  Please guide me regarding this things.

Here is my Code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#searchresult').autocomplete(
    {
        serviceUrl: 'source.php',
        minChars: 1,
        delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/, // regex or character
        maxHeight: 400,
        zIndex: 9999,
        deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
        noCache: false, //default is false, set to true to disable caching
        // callback function:
        onSelect: function(value, data){ alert('You selected: ' + value + ', ' + data); },
        // local autosugest options:
        lookup: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'] //local lookup values
    });
});
```

PHP CODE: source.php

```
<?php

    include "config/config.php";
    require "jsonwrapper/jsonwrapper.php";

    //$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));//retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends

    //$qstring = "SELECT description as value,id FROM tblcompanies WHERE description LIKE '%".$term."%'";

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT fieldDesc AS value, fieldID AS id FROM table");

    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))//loop through the retrieved values
    {
        $row['value'] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['value']));
        $row['id'] = (int)$row['id'];
        $data[] = $row;//build an array
    }

    echo json_encode($data);//format the array into json data

?>
```

Please share if you implement this type of jquery autosuggest. I'm happy for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Remove "lookup" option if you want to use results from the server.

Comment: but, still once I remove the "lookup" option, my PHP script is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, but the only problem I see is of lookup.

Can you pass a JSON Encoded array to js for lookup?

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#searchresult').autocomplete(
    {
        serviceUrl: 'source.php',
        minChars: 1,
        delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/, // regex or character
        maxHeight: 400,
        zIndex: 9999,
        deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
        noCache: false, //default is false, set to true to disable caching
        // callback function:
        onSelect: function(value, data){ alert('You selected: ' + value + ', ' + data); },
        // local autosugest options:
        lookup: resultArray
    });
});
```

result array here is JSON Encode php array passed to js for lookup.

Hopefully after doing this it will be fixed.